# Python, Graphql Mutation and Dango API

Tags: python, django, graphql

I am working on a project that takes signups from a Django form and transfers them to a website, the info is mainly the data ( Name, surname, email...) and some extra-information (tags).

One of the scripts give me the following error in the cronjob_logs;

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_cron/management/commands/runcrons.py",
> line 71, in run_cron_with_cache_check manager.run(force) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_cron/**init**.py", line
> 215, in run self.msg = self.cron_job.do() File
> "/home/django/django_project/ogx/cron.py", line 31, in do ep_id =
> get_ep_id(ep.email) File
> "/home/django/django_project/ogx/graph_helper.py", line 75, in
> get_ep_id ''', {"query": email}) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphqlclient/client.py", line
> 11, in execute return self._send(query, variables) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphqlclient/client.py", line
> 34, in _send raise e HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

The script was working normally some time ago, as for the graph_helper.py it is as follows;

```
def get_ep_id(email):
    client = GraphQLClient(
        '*this part I took off for confidentiality*')

    result = client.execute('''
        query Myquery($query: String!){
        allPeople(q:$query)
        {
            data
            {
              id
              full_name
                
            }
        }
    }
        
        ''', {"query": email})

    data = json.loads(result)
    if len(data['data']['allPeople']['data']) > 0:
        return data['data']['allPeople']['data'][0]['id']
    else:
        return None
```

The cron.py in question is the following;

```
class FetchEPsIDs(CronJobBase):
RUN_EVERY_MINS = 30  

schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
code = 'ogx.FetchEPsIDs'    # a unique code

def do(self):
    eps_query = mc_ogx_app.objects.filter(ep_id__isnull=True)
    for ep in eps_query:
        ep_id = get_ep_id(ep.email)
        ep.ep_id = ep_id
        ep.save()
```

As for the second script;

It is meant to update data called tags taken from the form and sent to the website through the API, now the script itself executes properly with no issues but it does not do what it is supposed to; Here you have the Cron...

```
class UpdateEpsTags(CronJobBase):
RUN_EVERY_MINS = 30  

schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
code = 'ogx.UpdateEpsTags'    # a unique code

def do(self):
    access_token = 'taken out for confidentiality'
    eps_query = mc_ogx_app.objects.filter(ep_id__isnull=False, tags_uploaded=False)
    for ep in eps_query:
        if len(str(ep.ep_id)) >= 2:

            tags_list = []
            if ep.country_pref is not None:
                tags_list.append(ep.country_pref.tag_id)

            if ep.career_pref is not None:
                tags_list.append(ep.career_pref.tag_id)

            first_tags_list = return_user_tag_list(ep)

            tags_list = tags_list + first_tags_list

            if ep.product_ogv:
                tags_list.append([7])

            if ep.product_oge:
                tags_list.append([9])

            if ep.product_ogt:
                tags_list.append([8])
            try:
                update_ep_tags(int(ep.ep_id), tags_list, access_token,ep.chosen_ref)
                ep.tags_uploaded = True
                ep.save()
            except:
                ep.save()
```

Now for the graphQl query in the script, it goes as follows;

```
def update_ep_tags(person_id, tags_list, token,referral):
client = GraphQLClient(
    'taken out for confidentiality')
result = client.execute('''
    mutation Mymutation($persons: [Int]!, $tags: [Int]!,$id: ID!, $referral: String!){
        bulkTagUpdateForPeople(person_ids:$persons, tag_list_ids:$tags)
        {
            id
            full_name
            tag_lists
            {
              id
              name
            }
        }
        updatePerson(id:$id , person:
              {
                referral_type:$referral
                
              })
              {
                full_name
                referral_type
                programmes
                {
                  short_name
                }
              }
    }

    ''', {"persons": [person_id], "tags": tags_list, "id": person_id, "referral": referral})
return result
```

Now executing the query on GraphQl I get Nullability mismatch on variable $id and argument id (ID / ID!).

Answer (score 0):

Tried checking the datatypes and also running the query on Insomnia to check if it works, it does work just fine, I do not seem to grasp where the error is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

What I am basically trying to do is reference using an email, the email is no longer supported by the API and therefor the query just gives a runtime error.